# Ruby Multi threading, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, elasticsearch

So, in order to improve to speed of our app I'm experimenting multi threading with our rails app.
Here is the code:

```
require 'thwait'
require 'benchmark'

city = Location.find_by_slug("orange-county", :select => "city, state, lat, lng", :limit => 1)
filters = ContractorSearchConditions.new()
image_filter = ImageSearchConditions.new()
filters.lat = city.lat
filters.lon = city.lng
filters.mile_radius = 20
filters.page_size = 15
filters.page = 1
image_filter.page_size = 5
sponsored_filter = filters.dup
sponsored_filter.has_advertised = true
sponsored_filter.page_size = 50
Benchmark.bm do |b|
  b.report('with') do
    1.times do
      cities = Thread.new{ 
        Location.where("lat between ? and ? and lng between ? and ?", city.lat-0.5, city.lat+0.5, city.lng-0.5, city.lng+0.5)
      }
      images  = Thread.new{ 
        Image.search(image_filter)[:hits]
      }
      sponsored_results_extended = Thread.new{ 
        sponsored_filter.mile_radius = 50
        @sponsored_results = Contractor.search( sponsored_filter )
      }
      results = Thread.new{
        Contractor.search( filters )
      }
      ThreadsWait.all_waits(cities, images, sponsored_results_extended, results)
      @cities = cities.value
      @images = images.value
      @sponsored_results = sponsored_results_extended.value
      @results = results.value
    end
  end
  b.report('without') do
    1.times do
      @cities = Location.where("lat between ? and ? and lng between ? and ?", city.lat-0.5, city.lat+0.5, city.lng-0.5, city.lng+0.5)
      @image = Image.search(image_filter)[:hits]
      @sponsored_results = Contractor.search( sponsored_filter )
      @results = Contractor.search( filters )
    end
  end
end
```

Class.search is running a search on our ElasticSearch servers.(3 servers behind a Load balancer), where active record queries are being runned in our RDS instance.

(Everything is in the same datacenter.)

Here is the output on our dev server:

```
Bob@dev-web01:/usr/local/dev/buildzoom/rails$ script/rails runner script/thread_bm.rb -e development
       user     system      total        real
with  0.100000   0.010000   0.110000 (  0.342238)
without  0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.164624)
```

Nota: I've a very limited knowledge if no knowledge about thread, mutex, GIL, ..

Comment: I'm no expert, but I see no point in having the overhead of managing threads when you're just going to wait for them all to finish anyway.

Comment: the ElasticSearch searches are taking too long to execute and it might be faster to execute them in parallel

Comment: What Ruby engine and version? You may have better luck with Rubinius or JRuby which have no global interpreter lock.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: does ElasticSearch support executing things in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot more overhead in the "with" block than the "without" block due to the Thread creation and management. Using threads will help the most when the code is IO-bound, and it appears that is NOT the case. Four searches complete in 20ms (without block), which implies that in parallel those searches should take less that amount of time. The "with" block takes 100ms to execute, so we can deduce that at least 80ms of that time is not spent in searches. Try benchmarking with longer queries to see how the results differ.

Note that I've made the assumption that all searches have the same latency, which may or may not be true, and always perform the same. It may be possible that the "without" block benefits from some sort of query caching since it runs after the "with" block. Do results differ when you swap the order of the benchmarks? Also, I'm ignoring overhead from the iteration (`1.times`). You should remove that unless you change the number of iterations to something greater than 1.

Comment: Thanks. The results do not differ when I swap the order. I use 1.times because my first try was with 100.times. Also when I try from my laptop(westcoast) the threaded block is 3times faster. the mysql and elasticsearch servers are in the westcoast. So with latency the threaded version is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are using threads, and hence performing query IO in parallel, you still need to deserialize whatever results are coming back from your queries. This uses the CPU. MRI Ruby 2.0.0 has a global interpreter lock. This means Ruby code can only run one line at a time, not in parallel, and only on one CPU core. In order to deserialize all your results, the CPU has to context switch many times between the different threads. This is a lot more overhead than deserializing each result set sequentially.

If your wall time is dominated by waiting for a response from your queries, and they don't all come back at the same time, then there might be an advantage to parallelizing with threads. But it's hard to predict that.

You could try using JRuby or Rubinius. These will both utilize multiple cores, and hence can actually speed up your code as expected.

Comment: To be sure I'm getting this correctly.
Using the threads might be faster as it sends the queries/get the results in parallel but doing things like `@cities = cities.value` actually slower the execution of the code ?

Comment: Whatever CPU work your threads are doing will make your code slow. Just imagine you constantly had to switch back and forth between cooking a meal, washing the dishes, and writing a novel. It would be more efficient to do each task one at a time. On the other hand, if you need to download 10 files, it makes sense to download all of them at once rather than wait for each one.